# Blocking UDP port 140 from receiving packets from source port 8989 (active way to send signal to sender that is unreachable)

Tags: networking, command-line, iptables, firewall, udp

So my problem is that I want to block UPD port 140 from receiving packets from port 8989, but I want to block it actively, not just silently ignore it, but to send an active signal to the sender of this packet that this port is blocked.

And on the online forums i could see that icmp is a good way for sending actively messages that it is denied.

And on this [forum](https://serverfault.com/questions/928620/iptables-udp-blocking-issue) it's almost the same question that i am in need the answer on that forum says :

```
Your iptables rule should REJECT with an ICMP port unreachable, e.g.:

-j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

or for IPV6:

-j REJECT --reject-with icmp6-port-unreachable
```

I tryed :

```
 iptables -A INPUT -p TCP --dport 80 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable tcp-reset
```

It's working but it's blocking port 80, i want to know if i can block 140 from port 8989 with this method ?

The command i tried :

```
iptables -A input -s 5.4.3.2 —dport 140 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
```

I have been trying to fix it for about three days now; I can't scratch my head around it. Can someone help? I am trying my best I tried the commands beloved, that i found on this [page](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/iptables-block-port/) but it doesn't show how to block from one port to another just only from ip addresses i need for port.

The code i found to block from ip addresses and i tried :
First I tried this one to port 140:

```
/sbin/iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport {140} -j DROP
```

Interface section use `eth1` but still I had to chose port 140:

```
/sbin/iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth1 -p udp --dport {8989} -j DROP
```

Only drop port for given IP or subnet:

```
/sbin/iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth1 -p udp --destination-port {140} -s {***.***.***.***} -j DROP
/sbin/iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth1 -p udp --destination-port {8989} -s {***.***.***.***} -j DROP
```

I think I am doing wrong the variable part, but I am reading the functions but none I find that I can choose a single port.

I did try but i was blocking all packets to 140 port not only 8989:

```
iptables -A INPUT -j DROP -p udp --destination-port 140 -i eth1
```

So one more time to reprise my question is if you had to block port 140 for udp on eth1 in an active way, for packets with source port 8989, but block it actively so not silently ignore, but to send active signal to the sender of this packet that this port is blocked, how would you it ??

Answer (score 1):

> /sbin/iptables -A ....

If you add this rule at the end of the chain then whether it is applied depends on the entries before it in the chain. Use '-I' to put it at the start of the chain.

If you want to block based on both the source and destination then you need to specify both the source and the destination.....

```
iptables -I INPUT -j REJECT -p udp --destination-port 140 --source-port 8989 -i eth1
```